# iframe редиректит всю страницу, вместо себя

Tags: html, iframe, redirect

есть сайт example.com

в нем встраивается iframe на othersite.com

в случае возникшей ошибки, iframe выдает код:

```
<form id="return" action='example.com/error' target='_parent'></form>
$(function(){$('#return').submit();});
```

Проблема, что редирект происходит на example.com, а необходимо, что бы сам iframe редиректнулся на example.com/error

Пробовал обернуть в 2 iframe но так example.com стал открываться в новом окне, что тоже не верно.
Пробовал давать id,name ifram'у равным "_parent", не получилось

Подскажите, что делаю не так, как решить задачу?

Comment: судя по всему надо убрать `target='_parent'` если нет доступа самому, обратитесь к разработчикам othersite.com

Comment: @Grundy ваше решение работает, но не знаете ли вы другого решения? (как вы и предположили, доступа к othersite нет, поменял в ручную отключив js для проверки) Самое интересное ,что раньше "layout" открывающий "othersite" был на стороне othersite, и код ошибки отрабатывал именно так, как нужно. Сейчас же, "layout" переехал к нам, но не удалось понять почему изменилось поведение.
(Ожидал что встроив iframe в iframe , получится такая же структура, как и тогда, когда "layout" был на othersite)

Comment: @Grundy в итоге буду писать разработчикам othersite. Оформите свое решение как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всему виной `target='_parent'`, нужно его убрать либо заменить на `target='_self'`.

Если нет возможности заменить самому, обратитесь к разработчикам *othersite.com*